# Is there a limit for Exosuit Upgrades?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have found one more Drop Pod and the hologram for the exosuit upgrade appears. But I don't get the three symbols to activate this upgrade.

Is there any limit for Exosuit Upgrades?
I think about # of Upgrades

- per planet?
- in a specific time?
- for a specific level / progress?
- anything else?

Actual used version of NMS: v1.75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only limit appears to be what the game allows: https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Exosuit

A total of 48 general slots, 14 technology slots (less for "legacy" players), and 48 high capacity cargo slots (25 for "legacy" players).

A legacy player seems to be anyone using a save created before the Atlas Rises update.

Comment: After a restart of the game at the same position, the unused Drop Pod was mysteriously empty and didn't show an upgrade. Then I found the next Drop Pod and everything works fine since then without any problems.